# std::string += operator

Tags: c++, string, stl

I'm having a bad couple of days for odd behaviour. I have a std::string on which I use the += operator to add another string (actually the name of a file being appended to a path). When I run the program I have found that the file was not being found. Copious couts later have revealed that I am getting the file name added to the start of the string.

```
std::string path("/home/me/location/");
std::string file("file.txt");
path += file;
std::cout << path.c_str();
```

The output from this is "file.txt/location"!!! I have tried a simple program which just adds two strings together and that works fine which I was expecting (gcc v 4.3). I have copied the code over from a windows machine, I wasn't expecting any issues beyond new file paths, it only really uses STL and dirent, indeed it compiled more or less first time. I ran dos2unix just in case. Now I'm a little bit stumped but I haven't really copied code over before beyond the totally trivial so I might be missing something blindingly obvious.

Comment: can you 100% exclude the possibility that `path` is *file.txt* and `file` is */home/me/location*? From here, it seems as though these variables contain values opposite of what you think they should.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger: note that the string "file.txt" does not get prepended but overrides part of his path string.

Comment: When using `std::cout` you can use the string directly without `c_str`. Also, are really sure you haven't mixed `path` and `file` somewhere? The code in your question should produce `"/home/me/locationfile.txt"`.

Comment: @KillianDS: Ok, in that case I'd assume that `file` starts with a *carriage return*. If this is the case, `file` would be appended to `path` but when cout'ed, it doesn't show so.

Comment: I am cout'ing all the components separately. I can hard-code this path in but further through I have a recursive directory search that also falls over completely that's harder to get around.

Comment: Use a debugger to debug, not `cout` (or stackoverflow.com). When something like this happens, you need to throw away all assumptions and see the data directly.

Comment: Please show us some actual, *runnable* code that exhibits this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the pathname somehow getting a "\r" appended to it, so that when you print it to cout it prints "/home/me/location/", returns to the start of the line, then prints "line.txt"?

As someone said, look at the variables with a debugger. (My instincts are for logging/printing too, but debuggers are useful too)

Comment: Argh, I didn't dos2unix the configuration file that was determining the paths. *facepalm*

Answer (score 1):

What you're missing is the `/` separator between the directory name and the file name.

Otherwise there is nothing wrong with the code you've posted.

One thing to bear in mind is that your code modifies the `path` variable. If you do `path += file` repeatedly for different file names, make sure to re-initialize `path` every time.

P.S. There is no way the four lines of code that you've posted can print out `file.txt/location`. Either the code that you've posted differs from what you're running, or the output isn't the same.

Comment: Or there is some code before these 4 lines which causes Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @Als: or some code *after* these 4 lines ;-) Unlikely, but it could happen either due to compiler optimizations or because the UB manifests in corrupting `stdout`'s buffer before it gets flushed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `file` starts with a *carriage return*. If this is the case, `+=` would still append `file` to `path`, but when the string is cout'ed, it would display the behaviour you describe.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `std::stringstream` for this:

```
std::stringstream tempss;
std::string path("/home/me/location");
std::string file("file.txt");

tempss << path;
tempss << file;

std::string filepath = tempss.str();
```

Comment: Why?  What's the point in having `+` for `std::string` if you can't use it.